# 12.10 video card Driver: <empty> Experience : limited

Tags: video

System details/ video card/Driver is empty and Experience shows "restreint" which means limited in french. My video card is : intel GMA 4500mhd, lscpi shows driver=i915 latency=0. I can only use gnome (no effects) and I would like to use Gnome3 again (as I did with ubuntu 12.04).
Thanks
[image: system details video card]

Xorg.conf is empty, and I would provide Xorg.0.log but I don't know how to attach it to this post.

Note: a 12.10 live usb works flawlessly on my machine. But I cannot reinstall everything.

Please help!!!

Comment: too hard a question??

Comment: please help!!!!!!

Comment: had you upgraded your ubuntu to 12.10 from a previous version?  It's possible that there are some old settings still lingering.

Comment: no I upgraded from 12.04... is it possible and how to clear all settings to default ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the mesa-utils package, which should help with the detection:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

From this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/183274/intel-gma-950-doesnt-work-on-asus-eee-pc-1000he

Comment: Thanks. But it is already installed, I tried removing and resintalling, but the problem is still here.

Comment: would it be possible to copy the config file from a live usb with 12.10?

Comment: if a live USB works correctly for you, you should be able to find the settings and copy/recreate them, yes.  Check the logs, lspci output and xorg configs when running from the liveUSB and add anything that seems useful on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on google and found someone had the [same problem](http://www.taringa.net/comunidades/ubuntuparataringeros/5453024/_Ayuda_-Con-Grafica-Intel-GMA-4500.html).

According to that user, the output of `lspci | grep VGA` was:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

So, do the same and if the ouput matches the one given above, [this](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm) may be the driver.

Hope this helps. I don't have that graphics card, so I don't know whether it will work for you. Let us know, please.

Comment: I just installed xserver-xorg-video-intel and resintalled mesa-utils....no effect. Thanks anyway. The driver page has now download link.

Comment: my output is: `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)` and a live 12.10 usb work well on my machine.