# VideoCard Driver, flash crash and low pixels?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

Some days ago I have been used Win 7, everything works fine and haven't problems that couldn't be solved!
At the time installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04!
First appearances was extremely positive, look good, have awesome speed of work, like terminal and multifunctionality, especialy installing mode, but:

1. In web pages where used flash content, usualy crash!
2. In flash game crash too!
3. Pixels look like was washed!

I looked at system properties and noticed :

- VGA card: Unknown
- Regime: Simple

I find something approach to me: [12.10 video card Driver: <empty> Experience : limited](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218945/12-10-video-card-driver-empty-experience-limited?rq=1)

After that:

- VGA card VESA: RS690
- Regime: Simple

What that mean ?
I don't have driver or isn't good ?

If I run:

```
    lspci | grep VGA
```

Then:

```
    01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690M         [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
```

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 [x64]
Toshiba Satellite A300D

Can somebody explain please how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want to do:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

The instructions you followed before were not for your graphics card. `fglrx` is the package name of the driver (named Catalyst) for supported ATI cards.

Comment: 0 Update pakets
0 Installed new pakets
4 Pakets haven't update

Comment: I will edit my answer.

Comment: ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

        What that mean ?

Comment: You should wait for the command to complete fully. It will then return to the prompt.

Comment: I know, everytime I'm waiting the command line !